# How to see historical follower statistics for Google Plus pages?

Tags: google-plus, followers, statistics, google-plus-pages

I'm a Google Plus page manager. I see how many followers my page has right this minute. But I can't see how many followers we had yesterday, or the week before. I'd like to know how many followers I had about a month ago.

Is there any way to do this natively with Google Plus?

What about with a service? (Hopefully, a free one.)

Answer (score 1):

You can us [CircleCount](http://www.circlecount.com/us/p/+google) to track followers. There used to be another one called socialstatistics.com but they appear to be gone now.